# Matching a regular expression in python pandas tuple

Tags: python, pandas

I want to match a regular expression by if-else loop like this in python pandas:

```
 df=pd.read('XYZ.csv');
Total_Data=df['Description'].str.extract(r'([0-9]+(\.[0-9][0-9]?)?\sGB|[0-9]+(\.[0-9][0-9]?)?\s?MB)')[0];
df['Total_Data']=Total_Data.str.extract(r'([0-9]{1,4})')

for row in Total_Data.iteritems() :
print (type(row))
if row.str.contains(r'((?i)MB)'):
df['Total_Data']=df['Total_Data']/1000;
```

Now I know whats wrong here `contains()` is for series in pandas.But then how should I iterate through rows in `Total_Data` so that if MB word is there in `Total_Data`,I could be able to convert it into GB.I want to check this reg ex and convert those tuple data which is in MB into GB
EDIT:

Subset of my data:

```
09       NaN
10       NaN
11       NaN
12       NaN
13       300 MB
14       NaN
15       NaN
16       NaN
17        80 MB
18       125 MB
19       200 MB
20         1 GB
21       250 MB
22       400 MB
23       350 MB
24         2 GB
25       500 MB
26         1 GB
27         1 GB
```

Comment: Can you share a head or a small subset of your data? Generally it should be simple, but I want to test before posting an answer. And there is no reason to use if and iteritems with pandas, you could accomplish it with apply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Regex Version**

First define a function to be applied, then apply. Change the return of the function if you want any changes to the output obviously.

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['Total_Data'] = [np.nan, np.nan, '300MB', '200 MB', '1 GB']

def process_row(row):
    match = re.match('^(\d+)\s*(MB)',str(row))
    if match:
        return str(int(match.group(1)) / 1000) + " GB"
    else:
        return row

df['Total_Data'] = df['Total_Data'].apply(process_row)

  Total_Data
0        NaN
1        NaN
2     0.3 GB
3     0.2 GB
4       1 GB
```

**'Pandas' version**

This one does some changes to the dataframe.

First let's replace NaN with empty string or anything to simplify life.

```
df['Total_Data'].fillna('0 None', inplace=True)
```

Then split a column as it looks like you have a space separated values.

```
foo = lambda x: pd.Series([i for i in x.split(' ')])   
df[['value', 'unit']] = df['Total Data'].apply(foo)
df['value'] = df['value'].astype('int')
```

You get something like:

```
Total Data  value  unit
0  0 None      0  None
1  0 None      0  None
2   80 MB     80    MB
3  200 MB    200    MB
4    2 GB      2    GB
5    1 GB      1    GB
```

The rest is simple. Get the index of entries to change and update them accordingly.

```
idx = df.loc[df['unit'] == 'MB'].index
df.loc[idx, 'value'] = df['value'] / 1000
df.loc[idx, 'unit'] = 'GB'
```

Comment: Actually I have scrapped data.Sometimes there is no space in between 200MB. I have to use a regular expression.Is there any other way by regular expression through which i can achieve this coz i need this somewhere else also

Answer (score 0):

Try the following and see whether it works,

```
 if (r'((?i)MB)') in row.str:
     df['Total_Data']=df['Total_Data']/1000;
```

I tried a small program using 'in' it worked. Hence suggesting if for you.

```
df="200MB"
if "200" in df:
   print "Yes"
Yes
```

Answer (score 0):

```
dtypes = {0:float, 1:object}
cnames = {0:'value', 1:'unit'}
replce = dict(unit=dict(MB=.001, GB=1.))
fmt = lambda x: np.nan if pd.isnull(x) else '{:0.3f} GB'.format(x)

df.Total_Data.str.split(expand=True) \
  .astype(dtypes).rename(columns=cnames) \
  .replace(replce).prod(1).apply(fmt)

0
9          NaN
10         NaN
11         NaN
12         NaN
13    0.300 GB
14         NaN
15         NaN
16         NaN
17    0.080 GB
18    0.125 GB
19    0.200 GB
20    1.000 GB
21    0.250 GB
22    0.400 GB
23    0.350 GB
24    2.000 GB
25    0.500 GB
26    1.000 GB
27    1.000 GB
dtype: object
```